# Variables seem to be changing type after they are declared

Tags: c#, casting, type-conversion

I've written this code for a learning exercise that I was working on and I'm using the c# Offline Compiler app for my Android phone if that happens to make a difference.

Whenever I try to run the program a compilation error pops up that tells me that I am trying to implicitly convert type int to byte. I've checked everything as best I can and I can't for the life of me find the issue and I couldn't seem to find the solution or the issue online. I have a feeling that it's something simple that I haven't learned yet. Here's the code...any ideas?

```
public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        for (byte i = 1; i < 255; i++)
        {
            byte mask = 4;
            byte filteredNumber;

            filteredNumber = i & mask;

            if (filteredNumber == 4)
                Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
    }
}
```

The issue seems to take place around the line `filteredNumber = i & mask;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because the `&` operator takes `int` values as parameters and returns an `int` value.

[image]

Try casting the result with

```
filteredNumber = (byte) (i & mask);
```